# Display flex not working inside Material UI Grid Item

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to place an element at the end of a Grid Item (horizontally). To do that I am wrapping my component with the following div component:

The full code:

```html
<Grid container spacing={8} alignItems={'stretch'}>
  <Grid item xs={9} >
    ...other components
    <div style={{  display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
      <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When I use the div component outside Grid the element floats to the right of the container but doesn't work inside Grid. Also note this Grid is imported from Material UI. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can do one thing. You can add another Grid container within the Grid item and put separate grid items for your components and div (with hello world). Did you get my point @Parichay?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I think you are trying to put "Hello World" to the right edge of the container... but yu had put it inside the Grid with `xs={9}`... to achieve it, just place your "Hello World" inside a Grid with `xs={12}`

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container alignItems={"stretch"}>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          ...other components
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              alignItems: "flex-end"
            }}
          >
            <p>hello world</p>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              alignItems: "flex-end",
              color: "red"
            }}
          >
            <p>I think you mean to do this... hello world</p>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-86rm4g)